# Passing {children} to layout component in NextJS & Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I would like to create a component for my main admin interface as a wrapper for the individual screens.

Essentially this JS code:

```
import Header from '../Header'
  
function TopNavbarLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <main>{children}</main>
        </>
    )
}

export default TopNavbarLayout
```

But in Typescript. When I try:

```
import Header from '../Header'

interface Props {
  children: JSX.Element
}

const TopNavbarLayout = ({children} : Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  )
}

export default TopNavbarLayout
```

I get the linting error that a type is expected and VsCode does not seem to recognize anything within <> and </>.

Does anyone have any advice for what I need to do to replace that JS component form above in TS?

The {children} I intend to send are different dashboards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct type for `children` is `ReactNode`, which is a union of all the kinds of things React accepts as children: `string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | null | undefined`. (That doesn't *seem* to support arrays as children, but it does via `ReactFragment`, which is `Iterable<ReactNode>`.)

```typescript
import { ReactNode } from "react";
// ...
interface Props {
    children: ReactNode;
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcARFATIwNwBQnA9D3ACkArgGd4KOGJQA7EgFpg0mtDgADABKoyUVZzJoANihZwDSeJpTaAXHAAUASjgBeAHyCAygA0AdAFEzECRpGC5ORRgkKGp0cgAFOjARXE44NLg0AAtgAxIWaVtkdBhiMi4KbjQIaTE4ABUIMEIUADcAI2MAGRQATwgheGd7PCycvODKWwTGkSc3FPS4FhghKCU7VMX0gB5XTa2t7cttOB49g4PtkBRFVxxR3PyKbZ5r2-3Ds4+HcvYgA)